# Java Reflection - Instantiation Exception Interface

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation

How can I realize with Java Reflection this case:

```
RequestDocument req = RequestDocument.Factory.newInstance();
```

I know how I can search a class and instantiate it but in this case I am unsure with the `.Factory.` before the new instance.

Comment: `RequestDocument.Factory` is just the class name, and you want to call the static method `newInstance` on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "realize with Java Reflection"? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Tunaki I think the OP wants to translate the above code into a reflective call - `Class.forName("com.package.RequestDocument.Factory).getMethod("newInstance").invoke(null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Factory` is a **static nested class** of `RequestDocument` and `newInstance` is a **public static** method, the equivalent of your code using **reflection** is then:

```
Object req = Class.forName("my.package.RequestDocument$Factory")
    .getMethod("newInstance")
    .invoke(null);
```

Please note the `$` used to indicate that it is an inner class and `null` used as object on which we want to invoke the method because it is a static call so no instance is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be:

```
RequestDocument req = Factory.class.newInstance();
```

but of course: when you already know package/Factory class; you should not use reflection. You simply call

```
RequestDocument req = new RequestDocument.Factory();
```

instead!